# mqtt+AWS AppSync: WebsocketConnectionError: WebSocket handshake error, connection not upgraded

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-appsync

I am using paho-mqtt Python library to implement subscriptions against AWS AppSync.

Here it is the code for the subscription:

```py
        postHeaders = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            **self._headers
        }

        payload = {
            "operationName": "onCommand",
            "query": """subscription onCommand($deviceId: ID!) {
                  onCommandCreated(deviceId: $deviceId) {
                    commandId
                    deviceId
                    command
                    arguments
                    status
                  }
                }
            """,
            "variables": {"deviceId": self._device_id}
        }

        r = requests.post(_ROOT_URL, headers=postHeaders, json=payload)
        try:
            r.raise_for_status()
        except Exception:
            self._exception('Could not subscribe to device commands, status %s, response %s', r.status_code, r.content)
            raise
        data = r.json()
        self._logger.info('Subscription response: %s', json.dumps(data, indent=3, sort_keys=True))

        # if data.get('errors'):
        #     raise ValueError('Error subscribing: {}'.format(data))
        client_id = data['extensions']['subscription']['mqttConnections'][0]['client']
        ws_url = r.json()['extensions']['subscription']['mqttConnections'][0]['url']
        topic = r.json()['extensions']['subscription']['mqttConnections'][0]['topics'][0]

        # noinspection PyUnusedLocal
        def on_connect(_client, _userdata, flags, rc):
            self._debug('Connected to subscription topic')
            client.subscribe(topic)
        urlparts = urlparse(ws_url)

        headers = {
            "Host": "{0:s}".format(urlparts.netloc),
        }

        client = mqtt.Client(client_id=client_id, transport="websockets")
        client.enable_logger(logging.getLogger('paho-mqtt'))
        client.on_connect = on_connect
        client.on_message = ...
        client.on_log = lambda *a, **kw: self._logger.info('On log', exc_info=True)
        client.ws_set_options(path="{}?{}".format(urlparts.path, urlparts.query), headers=headers)
        client.tls_set()

        self._debug('trying to connect now....')
        client.connect(urlparts.netloc, 443)
        try:
            client.loop_forever()
        except Exception:
            self._logger.exception('Error looping forever')
            raise
        finally:
            client.disconnect()
```

It works pretty well for about 24 hours, after which it starts failing, even despite its attempts to reconnect. I managed to intercept the exception that causes the failure:

```
May 01 20:39:21 ip-10-0-1-121 test_chattyraspi[8022]:   File "/home/ubuntu/chattyraspi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paho/mqtt/clie
May 01 20:39:21 ip-10-0-1-121 test_chattyraspi[8022]:     self.reconnect()
May 01 20:39:21 ip-10-0-1-121 test_chattyraspi[8022]:   File "/home/ubuntu/chattyraspi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paho/mqtt/clie
May 01 20:39:21 ip-10-0-1-121 test_chattyraspi[8022]:     self._websocket_path, self._websocket_extra_headers)
May 01 20:39:21 ip-10-0-1-121 test_chattyraspi[8022]:   File "/home/ubuntu/chattyraspi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paho/mqtt/clie
May 01 20:39:21 ip-10-0-1-121 test_chattyraspi[8022]:     self._do_handshake(extra_headers)
May 01 20:39:21 ip-10-0-1-121 test_chattyraspi[8022]:   File "/home/ubuntu/chattyraspi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paho/mqtt/clie
May 01 20:39:21 ip-10-0-1-121 test_chattyraspi[8022]:     "WebSocket handshake error, connection not upgraded")
May 01 20:39:21 ip-10-0-1-121 test_chattyraspi[8022]: paho.mqtt.client.WebsocketConnectionError: WebSocket handshake error, conne
May 01 20:39:21 ip-10-0-1-121 test_chattyraspi[8022]: 2020-05-01 20:39:21,194 - paho-mqtt - DEBUG - Connection failed, retrying
May 01 20:39:23 ip-10-0-1-121 test_chattyraspi[8022]: 2020-05-01 20:39:23,207 - client.raspi.alexa.mirko.io - INFO - On log
May 01 20:39:23 ip-10-0-1-121 test_chattyraspi[8022]: Traceback (most recent call last):
May 01 20:39:23 ip-10-0-1-121 test_chattyraspi[8022]:   File "/home/ubuntu/chattyraspi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paho/mqtt/clie
May 01 20:39:23 ip-10-0-1-121 test_chattyraspi[8022]:     self.reconnect()
May 01 20:39:23 ip-10-0-1-121 test_chattyraspi[8022]:   File "/home/ubuntu/chattyraspi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paho/mqtt/clie
May 01 20:39:23 ip-10-0-1-121 test_chattyraspi[8022]:     self._websocket_path, self._websocket_extra_headers)
May 01 20:39:23 ip-10-0-1-121 test_chattyraspi[8022]:   File "/home/ubuntu/chattyraspi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paho/mqtt/clie
May 01 20:39:23 ip-10-0-1-121 test_chattyraspi[8022]:     self._do_handshake(extra_headers)
May 01 20:39:23 ip-10-0-1-121 test_chattyraspi[8022]:   File "/home/ubuntu/chattyraspi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paho/mqtt/clie
May 01 20:39:23 ip-10-0-1-121 test_chattyraspi[8022]:     "WebSocket handshake error, connection not upgraded")
```

If I reboot the script, it starts back receiving notifications immediately.

[Here](https://github.com/fcracker79/chattyraspi/blob/master/clients/generic/chattyraspi/client.py) you can find the complete code.

I have added some more logs to dig into the issue. It seems to be that 
 AWS AppSync returns a `connection: keep-alive`, which causes the crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IoT disconnects WebSocket connection and requires authentication every 24 hours. You will need to redo Subscribe(basically the authentication and connect to the pre-signed URL) every 24 hours.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The failure is during the reconnection though. Moreover, paho-mqtt does not seem to provide some means to stop looping after an arbitrary amount of time.

Comment: Well, in the end I used `loop_start` and invoked `loop_stop` after 12 hours, then disconnect and reconnect. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: You are welcome. I would also recommend migrating to the pure WebSocket endpoint which provides better performance and scalability.
Reference: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/aws-appsync-adds-real-time-enhancements-with-pure-websockets-support-for-graphql-subscriptions/
Guide: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/appsync-websockets-python/